# How to get when lambda was last modified using boto3 and python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to use boto3 in a python script to get when a lambda was last updated. When I navigate to the lambda dashboard, I am able to see the last updated time as seen in my attachment.[image: last updated text]

Can I get the last modified value using boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [get_function_configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/get_function_configuration.html) on the Lambda function.

Use the `LastModified` string in the response.

Answer (score 0):

[Boto3 supports lambda GetFunction API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/get_function.html) which includes a ModifiedTime.